# Calculating y distance after 3d rotation?

Tags: math, 3d

I'll start off by saying that I'm quite bad in math,

I'm trying to calculate the distance between a circle and the center of the screen after rotating an image that contains that circle by 45 degrees in 3d,

(The y distance of the object changes as the image rotates)

[image]

I hope I made myself clear enough,
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Im not a genious, but I would say that you could use Distance= cos(angle)*(distance between center of the plane and the circle), its basically a right angled triangle where you can use cos(a)= adjacent/hypotenuse

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring perspective, the distance from the center of the screen follows a cosine. The height would be:

```
rotatedY = cos(angle) * originalY;
```

Subsituting 45 degrees results in

```
rotatedY = cos(45) * originalY = 0.707 * originalY;
```

So how about that, the circle will always be at 70% the height of the original unrotated Y value.

May I ask what you're trying to do? Maybe I can give you a better answer.

Comment: Hey and thanks for answering! I'm programming a game, I needed some help with math to create a camera that'll follow the player, the image in this question is actually the world of the game, the circle is the player

Comment: After trying this solution, it seems like I'm missing something, it just doesn't work as I want it to

Comment: I just read your other question. I see what you're trying to do but I don't think this is the right approach. Try setting the camera position to the player's position plus a constant offset. That would do it.